# Question about the intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, continuity

I am slightly confused by the answers in this thread

[Showing $\displaystyle{f(x) = \frac{x}{1 - |x|}}$ from $(-1, 1)$ to $ \Bbb R$ is surjective by way of calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582277/showing-displaystylefx-fracx1-x-from-1-1-to-bbb-r-is/3582297#3582297)

IVT requires (?) both the domain and range of a continuous function to be closed. If I understand the user Eric Towers correctly, for any $f(x_i) \in (-\infty, \infty)$, there's some $x_i \in (-1, 1)$ by IVT. I am thinking we can get away with the range $ (-\infty, \infty)$ being not closed because the limits show that all the $f(x_i)$ are attained/defined? But what about the domain of $f$? In the other answer, the user qbert uses IVT on the half-open interval $[0, 1).$ What part of IVT statement am I misunderstanding here? Thanks.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem examines the values between a point $a$ and point $b>a$ so that the closed interval $[a,b]$ is a *subset* of the domain.  It does not require the domain be closed because it doesn't say anything about the values outside the interval $[a,b]$.  And for the half open interval $[0,1)$ then they use a $b: 0 < b < 1$ and consider the IVT on that.

Comment: by the way $(-\infty, \infty)$ is closed.

Comment: @fleablood, nice to know $(-\infty, \infty)$ is closed. Guess I got it confused with another one of its properties: unboundedness.

Comment: So the idea is 1) pick an $r \in \mathbb R$.  2) Show that you can find a $b \in (-1,1)$ where $f(b) > r$ and show you can find an $a\in (-1,1)$ where $f(a) < r$. You have *not* used the IVT yet.  3) Now consider the closed interval $[\min(a,b),\max(a,b)]\subset (-1,1)$.  And note $f(a) < r < f(b)$.  *NOW* use the IVT.  4) There must exist a $c$ so that $-1 <\min(a,b) < c < \min(a,b) < 1$ so that $f(c) = r$.

Comment: @fleablood, I see. It looks like so long as we can find an $x$ in the closed subset of $f$ s.t. $f(x) = y \in f(-1, 1)$, we are good. Thanks.